# Extjs 4.0.7, Editor Grid - how to get updated cell value?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

I need to get(retrieve) updated cell value in controller. (MVC)

So I tried this,

```
var modified = this.getItemGrid().getStore().getUpdatedRecords();
console.log(modified); // return [] empty array

var modified = this.getItemList_Store().getUpdatedRecords();
console.log(modified); // return [] empty array
```

but always it returns empty array even I updated some cell value.

anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Here is my part of view code,

```
Ext.define("App.view.orders.ItemList_view", {
    extend: "Ext.grid.Panel",
    alias: "widget.itemList_view",
    plugins: [
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                clicksToEdit: 1
            })
    ],
    initComponent: function () {
        this.store = "ItemList_store";
        this.columns = [
            {
                xtype: 'checkcolumn', text: "Ship", width: 50, dataIndex: "DR"
            },
            { header: "test", width: 100, dataIndex: "test",
                editor: {
                    xtype : 'textfield'
                }
            }
        ];

        this.selModel = Ext.create("Ext.selection.CheckboxModel");
        //this.selModel = Ext.create("Ext.selection.CellModel"); // It does not works either.

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    .
    .
    .
```

Thank you!

[EDIT]

Thank you very much for your answer! I have some more question about editor grid.

Its much different from Ext3. so I'm very confusing now :(

**Q1. How to collect edited record data (once click button)?**

the event fired once the grid cell be changed.
but I want collect edited grid record once I click the 'Update edited cell' button, and I want to update all together at the once.

In Ext3, I did like this,

```
(button) click : function(){
    var modified = mygridStore.getModifiedRecords();

    var recordsToSend = [];
    Ext.each(modified, function(record){
        recordsToSend.push(record.data);
    });

    var grid = Ext.getCmp('grid');
    grid.el.mask('Updating','x-mask-loading');
    grid.stopEditing();

    recordsToSend = Ext.encode(recordsToSend);

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : '/test/test',
        params : {
            data : recordsToSend
        },
        success : function(response){
            grid.el.unmask();
            alert(response.responseText);
            mygridStore.commitChanges();
        },
        failure : function(response){
            mygridStore.rejectChanges();
        }
    });
}
```

How can I change the code for Extjs4 ?

**Q2. I don't know still how to find out for changed checkcolumn.**

I tried this, but I does not work for checkcolumn (of cause I tested after change checkbox)

```
// grid coumn
{
 xtype: 'checkcolumn', header: "My Check Column", width: 50, dataIndex: "CH"
}
```

-

```
// in control
'myGrid': {
    validateedit: function (plugin, edit) {
        console.log(edit);
    },
    checkchange: function (plugin, edit) {
        console.log(edit);
        console.log(edit.value);
    }
}
```

**Q3. When I click the cell to edit, the show some HTML tag in -_-;;**

[image]

***I really appreciate for your help. and thank you very much for your valuable time!***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The editors (cell editors or row editors) do not commit their values to the store until you complete the edit - which means pressing `ENTER` or blurring the active cell editor by clicking elsewhere on the page, or clicking the save button on the row editor form .

If your purpose for reading the updated value in your editor is to perform some kind of validation I would suggest simply listening to the `validateedit` event in your grid's controller, as described [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-validateedit).

The second argument that this event passes to your handler contains a lot of data about the edit that you can then perform validation with. If the edit doesn't pass your validation you can return `false` from your handler and the value in the celleditor will revert to it's original value. The `validateedit` event gets fired from the editor grid itself so you would add an event handler in your controller for it like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {

    init: function() {

        this.control({

            'mygridpanel': {

                validateedit: function(plugin, edit) {

                    // silly validation function    
                    if (edit.value != 'A Valid Value') {
                        return false;
                    }
                },

            },

        });

    },

});
```

But you should check out the link above to see all the different objects available in that second argument I named `edit`.

The `validateedit` event is fired right before the record is committed into the store - after the user has already clicked `ENTER` or blurred the editor, i.e., while the editor is closing.

If you are trying to get the celleditor's value *before* it starts to close, for some reason other than validation for example, you could get the active celleditor's value like this:

```
// myGrid is a reference to your Ext.grid.Panel instance
if (myGrid.editingPlugin.editing) {
    var value = myGrid.editingPlugin.getActiveEditor().field.value

    console.log('value: ' + value);
}
```

If there is no active editor then `myGrid.editingPlugin.getActiveEditor().field` would throw an error, that's why I wrapped a conditional around it.

One other point I should make, for validation in editor grids, I found that it is easiest to just put a `validator` config in the grid column's `editor` definition. That will give you all the handy validation CSS while the user is setting the field's value and alert him if there is a problem with the value before he tries to save it.

To get an idea of what I mean, try entering letters in the date column of [this example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/grid/cell-editing.html). Mouse over the editor cell and you will get the error message.

**EDIT**

It seems I misunderstood you original question, I'll break down my answers to your questions above though,

**Question 1**

Once you have completed an edit (clicked `ENTER` or ), your call to `mygridStore.getModifiedRecords()` should be working fine because the record will have been committed to the store. I see that it was not working, I will cover that in a moment.

I should point out that ExtJS4 has a `store.sync()` method as covered [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sync).

Instead of extracting the modified records from the store, encoding them, manually doing an ajax request to save them to the server and then manually committing them you can call this `sync` method and it will take care of all of these actions for you.

If you have different URLs to handle the different create, read, update, destroy operations fired off by your store's `load` and `sync` methods, you can use the store's proxy `api` config to map your URLs to these operations as covered [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-api). Or you can set-up your server side controller to be able to differentiate between your store's `load` request (read operations default to HTTP GET) and it's sync requests (create, update and delete operations default as HTTP POST).

There could be many different ways to go about doing this on the server side, the way I usually do it is to have one SQL stored procedure for GET requests and one for POST requests for any given store. I include the store name as an extra param and then my server side controller runs the appropriate stored procedure based on whether it is a GET or a POST request.

**Question 2**

Cell editing doesn't support `checkcolumn` edits. You have to make a different handler to listen to changes on that, something like this:

```
checkchange: function (column, rowIndex, checked) {
    var record = store.getAt(rowIndex),
        state = checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'

    console.log('The record:');
    console.log(record)
    console.log('Column: ' + column.dataIndex);
    console.log('was just ' + state)
}
```

Your call to `mygridStore.getModifiedRecords()` should be able to pick up the check changes also however, they get committed to the grid's store right away after being checked. `store.sync()` would also pick up changes to checkcolumn.

**Question 3**

I can't completely tell what is causing that problem but it may be something strange going on with your `validateedit` event, your handler should be returning true or false.

As I said earlier, I misunderstood the reason you originally asked this question. I thought you were trying to do some kind of validation *while* an edit was in progress. Now I understand that you are trying to get all of the modified records from the store after all the editing is completed in order to save them to the database, I was thrown off because in ExtJS 4 a store is usually saved to the database with the `sync` method as I mentioned.

In other words, you don't need the `validateedit` event or `checkchange` event to get a list of modified records.

The actual problem you are having might be trouble with the store's getter methods (`getModifiedRecords`, `getUpdatedRecords`) in some 4.07 versions, take a look at [this post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-170183.html?s=411caff4c3c5759c6044d958e83785b9) and [this one](http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-164251.html?s=05b94218754784752b0e79b8c9eda0a9).

So with all that said, the best advice I can give you is 1) try out the stores `sync` method for saving modified data to the database and 2) upgrade to ExtJS 4.1, there were *a lot* of bugs that were straightened out between 4.07 and 4.1 which you should be able to take advantage of, I cut out about 75% of the overrides I was using to make things work when I switched over to 4.1.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but still I can not solve my problem yet, could you help me a little more please?

Answer (score 1):

```
EditedGrid.plugins[0].completeEdit();
```

This will make the active changes commit and call edit event also.

Answer (score 0):

```
listeners: {
    validateedit: function (editor, e) {
        //console.log(editor);
    var oldVal = editor.originalValue;
    var newVal = editor.value;
    }
}
```