# show/hide column in grid conditionally in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have grid in my application, I need to show/hide particular column conditionally. Please help me.

Code:

```
{
    header: 'Type',  dataIndex: 'mirror',  flex: 1, sortable: true,
    renderer: function (value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                    if(value == '')
                        return "-";
                    else
                        return value;
            }
}
```

currently it shows `-` incase no records,but I need to remove column incase no record found.

Comment: Go through this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196873/extjs-4-0-7-editor-grid-how-to-get-updated-cell-value"

Hope this one will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns have a `hide` method which you can use. For example, take a  look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/tdwjN/) that show you how to hide an specific column in runtime.

If you want to `hide/show` a the column depending on a condition, you have to evaluate that condition and use the `hide` & `show` methods.

Comment: can we write this function in renderer ?

header: 'Job',  dataIndex: 'job',  flex: 1, sortable: true,
    renderer: function (value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
     -------------
    }

Comment: yes, you can use it in the renderer function if you want to. Question: was my answer useful for you?